# Eclipse with ADT 22.6.0 Outline View is Empty When a layout XML open with Android Common XML Editor

Tags: android

[Q:Eclipse Outline View is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8504740/1501458) is not work for me.

ADT version : 22.6.0

Eclipse version : 4.2

**My Question : How to show outline When Editting in Android Common XML Editor?**

Text Layout：
[image]

Graphic Layout：
[image]

Comment: @gabor.orosz Sorry.I just re-install the ADT to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

1. Under Help, Click on "Install New Software"
2. Click on the Hyperlink "Available Software Site"
3. Click on the ADT and click the edit button on the side
4. Copy out the location and click the remove button
5. Click on the Add button - Add Repository; and paste the location
6. This will re-install the Android ADT.
   Issue should be solved ...